# how to mock jquery calls from within a function using jasmine and sinon

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

First, this is a job requirement. If it can't be done this way I need a good argument to give.

I have to test our backbone project using jasmine and sinon. I can't figure out how to mock a jquery call within a function. I have a function like this (cleaned up a little to discard extraneous calls):

```
Project.Views.FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
  sidenavClicked: function(event){



    var sidenav_id = $(event.target).attr('id').split('m')[1];
    var sidenav_num = sidenav_id.split('m')[1];

    var form_id = $('div.active form').attr('id');
    var form_num = form_id.split('m')[1];

    //code for fast scrolling
    this.slideTo(form_num-1, sidenav_num-1);

    return false;
  },
  ...
});
```

right now I'm just trying to test that slideTo() gets called this is my jasmine spec

```
describe("Form", function(){
    describe("Carousel", function(){

    it("should call slideTo when navbar is clicked", function(){
        var spy = sinon.spy();
        var formView = new Project.Views.FormView({ el : $('#main'), id : 1});
        formView.bind('slideTo', spy);

        var event = {};
        event.target = "<div id='form1'></div>";

        formView.sidenavClicked(event);
    });
});
```

the error message is: TypeError: form_id is undefined in file:  .../src/main/webapp/js/views/FormView.js

Which as far as I can tell is because there is no document for jQuery to match against. How can I get form_id to have a value?

The actual code does work and does do what it is supposed to do.

Update: The html looks something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <ul id="carousel-navbar">
            <li><a id="navlink-form1">Text</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
        <div id="formCarousel" class=" carousel slide" >
            <div class="active first item">
                <form id="form1" name="question1">
                    ...
                </form>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

to clarify not exactly like this (the actual one is 442 lines), but the structure should be synonymous where relevant.

Comment: Inside of it. I'll update answer.

Comment: If it is inside the `el` then you should be using [`this.$()`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) instead of `$()` anyway, that might even solve your problem too (but I don't know enough about your stack to know for sure).

Comment: yeah I had tried this.$() already. The problem is that the jasmine tests are not attached to any html that I am aware of so there is nothing that is being selected from by the jQuery selector. If that isn't correct, please let me know.

Comment: The code running on the server does work correctly.

Comment: Can you just pass in the html you showed above to the FormView constructor? As long as you then use this.$(), it should work against your mocked HTML.

Comment: I could, but then I just have all this extra logic (to take an optional html argument that it should only use if called from the jasmine tests) written in the live code to make tests pass, in an object that is already way more complicated than it should be. Also, does that not defeat the purpose of testing?

Comment: I may have misunderstood I tried setting preferenceView.$el.html(test_html_stuff) which is what I think you were saying. It did not work any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the element you are looking for is not attached to the DOM. You have to add it before you call your function:

```
it("should call slideTo when navbar is clicked", function(){
    var spy = sinon.spy();
    var formView = new Project.Views.FormView({ el : $('#main'), id : 1});
    formView.bind('slideTo', spy);
    $('body').append('<div class="active"><form id="form1" /></div>');


    var event = {};
    event.target = "<div id='form1'></div>";

    formView.sidenavClicked(event);
});
```

There are also some plugins for easier fixture handling with jasmin: [jasmine-fixture](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-fixture) or [jasmine-dom](https://github.com/jeffwatkins/jasmine-dom)

Comment: I had tried many different ways of adding it. This way worked-ish though. Best way I have found. The issues obviously with this way are (for future users) now the html from jasmine spec has extra html (it just needs to be cleaned up at the end of each test), and the slightly larger issue that means that this.$() can't be used (the way you should if possible be using jquery calls with backbone). I appreciate your help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem a little naive, but I'll point it out anyway.

It seems to me that you're not actually rendering the view anywhere. I say this simply because none of the code you posted calls `.render()` on the view and I can't see anything that would suggest it's happening behind the scenes, and that might explain why the JQuery call is behaving the way it is.

Rendering views from within a Jasmine spec is usually as simple as this:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  // some element you want to render your view into
  $('#testbed').html(view.render().el);
});
```

`form_id` might be undefined because the element you're looking for is not in the DOM. Can you actually find that element at all from within the function? And from within the test itself?

(Also, because that function is bound to an event, I personally feel it would probably make more sense to call it by triggering that event - `.click()` or whatever on the div for example - rather than explicitly call it.)

Comment: I have tried this like this there is still some issue rendering it when not calling everything the way it should naturally be.